# Cannot access Apache 2 virtual host on localhost

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, localhost, linuxmint

I originally set my web root in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` to point to `/home/me/www`.  Due to the requirements of a new project, I need to be able to set `/home/me/www/vendor/www` as its own virtual host as any local directory cruft in the request stemming from `localhost/blah/blah/blah` will currently cause it to fail (the site is pretty horrible, codewise, which is why I've been contracted to work on it).

I have the following config file in my `/etc/apache2/sites-available` -

`project2.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName project2
    ServerAlias localcopy
    ServerRoot /home/me/www/vendor/www/
    DocumentRoot /home/me/www/vendor/www/
    <Directory /home/me/www/vendor/www>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.

    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I also have the following entry in my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Shevat
127.0.1.2   project2.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

However, when I attempt to access `project2.com` through my browser, it displays the contents of the `/home/me/www` directory instead because, like I said above, I set that as my global web root in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`.

Is there a way to override the global web root/virtual host settings in this instance so project2.com is accessed properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the full hostname when setting the ServerName parameter:

```
ServerName project2.com
```

Since you left off the '.com' apache doesn't know to send you there.